# Schedule a background task (Cron Job) for a specific date and time

Tags: asp.net-core, scheduled-tasks

I am creating an ASP NET Core app, and I have certain entities, for example, a dispute for an order. After the dispute has been opened, the Creation Date property is set for it. I want to make sure that if the buyer does not answer in his dispute within 7 days, the dispute is closed automatically.
I understand that it can be done through CronJob with a certain interval, but I would like to avoid an excessive number of calls to check the date in all disputes.

Is there a proper way to schedule task calls at a specific time? I need it workable even after app restarting.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a proper way to schedule task calls at a specific time?

To execute a background task/job at a user specified time, you can try to use some message queue services, such [Azure Queue Storage queues](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/queues/storage-tutorial-queues?toc=%2Fazure%2Fstorage%2Fqueues%2Ftoc.json&tabs=dotnet) that enable us to specify how long the message should be invisible to Dequeue and Peek operations by setting [`visibilityTimeout`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/azure.storage.queues.queueclient.sendmessageasync?view=azure-dotnet#Azure_Storage_Queues_QueueClient_SendMessageAsync_System_BinaryData_System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__System_Nullable_System_TimeSpan__System_Threading_CancellationToken_).

And you can implement a queue triggered background task to retrieve message(s) from the queue and close the dispute in code logic.

Comment: For local development and testing purposes, you can try to test code against the storage services locally using [Microsoft Azure Storage Emulator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-emulator) without creating an Azure subscription or incurring any costs.